# ERROR Message: The coordinates of the range are outside

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am really struggling with this, the script is quite straightforward, the only thing is I only want it to sort from row 3 onwards, that is what makes it go wrong, if I set the get.Range to (1,1) then it works, but I need those two rows for headers!
Also the top two rows are frozen (if that makes any difference).
Any help on this would be amazing!!!
I have tried all the other forum solutions (+1 or - 1 on the range but still nothing.

```
function sortSpreadSheet(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange(3,1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```

Comment: You start at row 3. You then access the next *{{total number of rows}}*. This will always be beyond the actual dimensions of the sheet...

Answer (score 2):

Frozen rows are ignored when sorting, so just grab the sheet's [datarange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and sort:

```js
sheet.getDataRange().sort(/* your options here*/);
```

The source of the error is in your [`Sheet#getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) call, as you don't account for the header row offset of **2**:

```js
const numHeaders = 2;
const range = sheet.getRange(1 + numHeaders, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - numHeaders, sheet.getLastColumn());
range.sort(...);
```